# Extjs quicktip display empty box

Tags: gwt, extjs, tooltip, gxt

I am trying to implement a tool tip (QuickTip) functionality on a GXT grid cell.It seems to work most of the time, but some times I get an empty tooltip box while mousing over the column header. I found some articles stating the tooltip is only applicable to the data and not on header,but thats not the case I guess. I made the toolTip/text null by default, still I see empty box on header-mouse over.Am I doing something wrong?
This is my code:

```
ColumnConfig columnTitle = new ColumnConfig();
    columnTitle.setId("subject");
    columnTitle.setHeader("<B>Title</B>")
    columnTitle.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<ModelData>()
    {
        @Override
        public Object render(ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,
                ListStore<ModelData> store, Grid<ModelData> grid)
        {
            SystemUserMessage msg = ((BeanModel)model).getBean();
            String text = null;
            text = msg.getSubject();

            String content = model.get("content").toString();
            String toolTip = null;
            toolTip = " qtip='" + content + "'";
            String style = null;
            if(msg.getPriority().equals("High"))
            {
                style = " style='color: red;'";
            }
            String html = "<span" + toolTip + style + ">" + text + "</span>";
            return html;
        }
    });
```

new QuickTip(messageCenterGrid); //register the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `qtip=` with `data-qtip=` . You can also add `data-qtitle=`

**Edit** helpful link per Juan : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTipManager

Comment: @decentguy The attributes have been renamed, see this page for what attributes to set http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTipManager

Comment: @JuanMendes , i modified to data-qtip, but now its not working at all, looks like I am not using the latest version

Comment: @decentguy Then you should update your question to specify the version of Ext-JS you're using, that'll be more helpful than what version of GXT

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194571-Use-of-QuickTip-leads-to-empty-tooltips

Comment: @JuanMendes, looks like this is a bug.  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194571-Use-of-QuickTip-leads-to-empty-tooltips

Comment: That may be the same issue, but that is using GXT 3, while your post appears to be GXT 2. Worth pointing out: GXT does not use Ext JS at all, so there is no Ext JS version to check when using GXT.